# Can't switch to GeForce GTX 960M in Nvidia X Server Settings

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Title says it all, for some reason I lack the capability of switching to my Nvidia card. I installed the necessary drivers through the "Additional Drivers" dialog. I also have uninstalled default drivers but to no go. Here are some images detailing the situation. Thanks in advance for any and all answers/assistance!

Nvidia Control Dialog:
[image]

Ubuntu System Details:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Disable Secure Boot on BIOS.

Comment: What version did you install? Is the card enabled in BIOS? Are you sure it isn't already in use?

Comment: Did you install the drivers through `apt-get`?

Comment: Just disabled Secure Boot, no difference unfortunately. Booting using UEFI: Safe Boot Off. Can't find where to enable the card in the bios but Ubuntu does recognise it. And I did not install using apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with a combination of methods from all who answered. :) First disabled secure boot, then removed the drivers with:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

and then reinstalled with:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
reboot
```